# How to store the result of a loop over combinatoric pairs of a list?

Tags: r, list, loops, combinatorics

I have a matrix (but for the purposes of the example I will simplify to a vector).

I  want to loop over all pairs of the list. So if the list is length n (or the matrix has n columns), the resulting list has to be (n choose 2) items long.

Suppose n = 6 for the example, but in reality is 36.

Basically, I want a loop like this:

```
list=1:6

endlist= vector("list", 15)   # 15 from 6!/((4!)(2!))
```

Here is what I want:

Note the below loop does NOT work since there is no i index, and there appears to be no linear combination of j and k that fits the index.  Is there a nonlinear one?  Or is there a better way to program this?

```
for(j in 1:5){  
    for(k in (j+1):6){
        endlist[[i]]=list[j]*list[k] 
    }
}
```

Giving the output:

```
endlist=
[[1]]
[1] 2 3 4 5 6 

[[2]]
[1] 6 8 10 12
```

etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's definitely a better way to code that. I'm not sure how this will necessarily apply to your matrix, but for your example:

```
combn(list, 2, prod)
#[1]  2  3  4  5  6  6  8 10 12 12 15 18 20 24 30
```

`combn()` produces combinations of a vector, and can apply a function to each combination(`prod`). If you really want the output as a list, you can do it with `split()`:

```
split(combn(list, 2, prod), rep(1:(max(list)-1), times =(max(list)-1):1))
# $`1`
# [1] 2 3 4 5 6
# 
# $`2`
# [1]  6  8 10 12
# 
# $`3`
# [1] 12 15 18
# 
# $`4`
# [1] 20 24
# 
# $`5`
# [1] 30
```

I think the takeaway here is that it's better to calculate your combinations, and work on those, rather than create the combinations yourself in some kind of loop.

Comment: If you wanted to get all pairs of columns in a matrix multiplied by each other and store the output, can you still use this function?